# Vaadin23 tooltip component

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I need to show users different tooltips on mouse over event. Do we have something like that in Vaadin component library? If no, how to show tooltips in Vaadin23?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an addon for tooltips https://vaadin.com/directory-beta/addon/tooltip

There is also ongoing work on adding tooltips to the core framework, you can follow the discussion here https://github.com/orgs/vaadin/discussions/3196

Answer (score 3):

You could use also get the root element of whatever component you want the tooltip for and set the attribute:

```
Button button = new Button("Example");
button.getElement.setAttribute("title", "This is the tooltip");
```